# Asking user to create a direct account after registering from Facebook Connect / Twitter OAuth

Tags: facebook, twitter-oauth

We're planning to have a sign-up page that allows users to use Facebook Connect or Twitter to sign in. After they validate their account and we fetch their information from their parent site, it is an acceptable thing to ask them to create a **direct** login/password for our site?

I've not seen sites do this, but I havent really used FB-connect that much as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceptable? That really depends on your users and their expectations but I would wonder why a site using this tactic wouldn't just ask me to create a local account in the first place.

Generally, the industry seems to be moving towards trusted third party user authentication, like Facebook, Twitter or OpenID.

The value to a user of allowing her to sign-in to your application using a third-party service (in which she already has an account) is to reduce the number of accounts she must keep track of, so requiring her to create yet another account would seem to make such a benefit moot.

Of course, there is nothing stopping you from creating a local user model to hold custom user data where authentication is handled either via passwords or by a third party, as in:

```
create table user (
  user_id int primary key
  name varchar,
  validated_by enum('password','facebook','twitter', etc.)
  /* other custom fields here */
);

create table password (
  password_id int primary key,
  user_id int foreign key,
  value varchar
);
```

And create business logic to "do the right thing" in all cases.